# What factors should be considered when designing database that includes parent and child entities?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

What factors should be considered when designing a database structure to support parent and child?  Would one include parent and child within a single table that includes both parent and children (only one level deep)?  Or a different approach?

For example, question and answer entities where the question and answer have the same attributes (e.g., text, date added).

Comment: Is it really "question" and "answer"?

Comment: Literally, 'parent and child' suggests a (family) tree, therefore look at "nested sets" and "adjacency list model". But you may mean 'referenced and referencing tables'. in which case look at "foreign key".

Answer (score 2):

How many "columns" are needed to describe a "parent"?  How many for a "child"?  How many overlap?

I once studied a forum-type schema; it had the "threads" and the "comments" in the same table.  Some columns were used for both; many were not.  In my analysis, I decided that performance, clarity, etc, would benefit from having two tables.  (In this case, a "child" ("comment") could have children.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to close this as a matter of opinion.  However, you give a specific example.

In most applications "questions" and "answers" are two different entities.  Hence, they should be in two different tables.

There are some circumstances where you would put related entities into a single table.  I don't think questions and answers are such an example.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I updated question to avoid opinion answers.